# Migrating OS X Server from Macbook Pro to Mac Mini

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-mini, server.app, migration

We are running Mac Server version 5.1.5 on a MacBook pro running the latest version of El Capitan. We want to migrate this install to our MacMini running the same exact OS and Server versions.

What is the quickest and most efficient way to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: Thanks Guys,

I will try these methods this week. I will let you know how I make out.

Answer (score 1):

Tony, you might want to have a look at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202848

> **Migrating your Server**
>
> You can migrate from OS X Server on Mavericks or Mountain Lion to another >computer using OS X Yosemite. Use the Setup Assistant or Migration Assistant >included with Yosemite to transfer your data before you open Server app.
> You can migrate server data using one of the following methods:
> A server connected in Target Disk Mode
> A local hard drive or partition with OS X Server installed
> A local Time Machine backup of OS X Server
> Migrating over a network connection, either from an existing server or a Time >Machine backup, is not an available option for OS X Server.
>
> To migrate your server:
> Use Setup Assistant on a new Mac, or open the Migration Assistant from the >Utilities folder.
> Follow the onscreen instructions. Select a supported connection method when >prompted.
> When migration is complete, download and install Server from the Mac App Store
>
> Open the Server app and follow the onscreen instructions to complete
> the server setup.
> If you open Server app before migrating your server data, remove Server app >before migrating and then reinstall it after migration is done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Mac Mini is compatible (the flat, all-aluminium ones are) the simplest way to move the whole server is do exactly that - copy the entire drive.

Get Carbon Copy Cloner, reboot the Mini in Target Disk mode and connect it to the MacBook with a suitable cable. The Mini will appear as if it was an external drive.

Open Disk Utility and reformat the drive in the Mini.

Open Carbon Copy Cloner, select the MacBook's drive as source, the Mini's drive as destination, click clone and wait a bit. Reboot the Mini and it will be the same as your MacBook.

Yes, you can do this while the MacBook is running. Yes, you can copy the OS between machines. No, you don't need to install OS X before copying.

This used to be a 10-minute job - just pull the drive and install in the new machine. Modern construction makes that nearly impossible now.

You will have to adjust minor things like the Mini's IP address, but it doesn't take long to run through System Preferences and Server.